# Why won't this handle the enter event of EditText for a list?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a EditText, and a listview, and a button "Add". I want it so that when the user hits the enter/return/add button in their keyboard, it does the same action as "Add". It should add the entered string value to the listview by adjusting the arrFencer string Arraylist and informing the attached adapter "adapter".

However, when I do this code, the AVD just minimizes the keyboard and does not add it to the listview. What am I doing wrong?

```
    //setup name Actions
    final EditText nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    nameEditText.setImeActionLabel("Add", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);

    //add the name when Enter is hit
    nameEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                //add name to list
                arrFencers.add(nameEditText.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                nameEditText.setText("");
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
```

Edit: FYI the editText has a `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` setup

Comment: first put a log in you editorAction and see if it is being hit so you know if it is an adapter issue or a keyboard issue

Comment: I have set the "android:imeOptions="actionNext", and the actionID does not match the IME_ACTION_NEXT code/ID. Did I not set it up correctly?

Comment: if you put a break point on the if statement and hit it when pressing the next button, what is the value of action id?

Comment: actionId =66, and IME_ACTION_NEXT = 5

Comment: hmm. have you tried setting the ime action of the edittext in the xml instead of code

Comment: I have `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` , but that's it.

Comment: try making the edittext singleline = "true"

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || 
    (event != null && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
```